# Add Datasource to Existing Layer using Maps Engine API

Tags: google-maps-engine

I'm using the Maps Engine API to bulk load rasters.  I have code that will upload a raster as a datasource, but I don't see how it is possible to add that data source into an existing layer.

If I create a new layer, I can specify a list of data sources to include.  I'm adding quite a few rasters so I need the ability to add to a layer that already exists.

Here is a snippet of code that I have so far:

```
fileupload = {
"projectId": id,
"name": "Test API Upload - Name",
"description": "Test API Upload - Description",
"files": filenames,

"draftAccessList": "Map Editors",
"attribution": "Copyright My Copyright",
"tags": ["testAPIUpload"],
"maskType": "autoMask",
"rasterType": "image"
}

rasters = service.rasters()
request = rasters.upload(body=fileupload)
response = request.execute()

try:
    rasterUploadId = str(response['id'])


    for name in raster_files:
        print "Waiting for 2 seconds"
        time.sleep(2)

        try:
            freq = rasters.files().insert(id=rasterUploadId,
                                          filename=name,
                                          media_body=name)
            print "Calling insert request"
            freq.execute()
            print "Finished uploading %s" % name
        except Exception:
            print "Unable to insert '%s'" % name

except KeyError:
    print "Error uploading raster files"
    print response
```

Now that I have my rasters uploaded, how can I add them to a layer that already exists?

Thank you,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing layer and wish to update it with datasources as you publish them then you can use the [layer patch](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/layers/patch) method.

You'll need to make sure you include the existing data sources as sending a patch request with data sources provided will set the layer to use those data sources, dropping anything not included.